# jquery-ui-map zoom does not automatically adjust down with fewer markers

Tags: jquery-ui-map

Conditions: map api  v3, jquery ui map, add marker bounds true.

Operation: 
1.When I add markers the zoom properly and automatically adjusts to include all the markers.

1. However, as I decrease the quantity of makers the zoom does not  re-adjust to
   include the remaining  markers.

Is this a bug, does anyone know of a  site where I can test this.
I can provide a url if more information is needed.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

After each new marker is added, the bounds need to be updated like so:

```
$('#map_canvas').gmap('addBounds', marker.position);
```

If you ever need to reset the bounds totally, remove markers, or add a new set of markers, you can do this:

```
$('#map_canvas').gmap('clear', 'markers');
$('#map_canvas').gmap('set', 'bounds', null);
```

Hope that helps you next time, or a Googler :)